# Certain websites redirect to 127.0.0.1. How do I fix this?

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet, browser, localhost

Facebook and Youtube in particular.

Tried nslookup the address shows as 127.0.0.1.
Checked the HOSTS file, it's fine.
Ran Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware (didn't find any problems) and SpyBot Search and Destroy (found 1 problem).

(Not sure if the Spybot made this improvement) now pinging youtube shows the correct address (74.125.71.91) but the browser still says:

> ```
> Connection to 127.0.0.1 Failed
> ```
>
> The system returned:
>
> ```
> (111) Connection refused
> ```

Tried `ipconfig /flushdns` but there are no changes.

Switched to another user but the results are the same.

---

hosts file:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

---

ipconfig all:

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix: 
DNS Servers: 10.1.1.30
208.67.220.220
```

Comment: What is in your hosts file?

Comment: And what is your dns set to `ipconfig /all`

Comment: added info to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like someone may be blocking sites on the network (parents? school? boss?)

Comment: Checked my seatmate's connection. His is just fine.

Comment: This is weird...

Comment: Could your system be using an alternate hosts file or some sort of proxy or a weird browser setting?

Comment: browser settings are the same (as the time when those sites were fine). i don't think were using alternate hosts files (how do i check something like that?)

Comment: i think i should mention that this morning i could access the sites just fine.

Comment: I don't know, unfortunately, and are you using a SOCKS/HTTP proxy, and a network admin can easily only block your traffic - this happened while I was torrenting ubuntu at uni today

Comment: weird... very weird.

Comment: the admin could be targeting you o.O

Comment: @Dian try not to come off as rude... you might accidentally sound impertinent

Comment: yeah, i'll keep that in mind. though, he's a pretty chill guy.

Comment: @Dian good luck!

Comment: turns out you were right, admin guy says the big boss decided to be strict. just took awhile for the restrictions to kick in but now everybody can't access these sites. bummer.

Comment: @Dian oh neat! bahaha that's kinda funny. use a SOCKS proxy to get around anything :)

Comment: yep! enjoy your day